# Regular Expression to test an entire word

Tags: regex

i have this expression `([a-zA-Z]|ñ|Ñ)*` which i want to use to block all characters but letters and Ñ to be entered on a textbox.
The problem is that return a match for: A9023 but also for 32""". How can i do to return a match for A9023 but not for 32""".
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add assertions for the start and the end of the string:

```
^([a-zA-Z]|ñ|Ñ)*$
```

Otherwise the regular expression matches at any position. Additionally, you can also write `([a-zA-Z]|ñ|Ñ)*` as the character class `[a-zA-ZñÑ]*`:

```
^[a-zA-ZñÑ]*$
```

Comment: also, Expresso is a great tool for testing regex... http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Answer (score 0):

Sure that you don't mean **`^`**`([a-zA-Z]|ñ|Ñ)*`**`$`** -- you might be finding the characters you want but not excluding what you don't? The expression I mentioned will pin to the beginning `^` and the end `$` of the string, so that nothing else will pass. Otherwise:

```
123ABC456
```

...will pass your match, because it found 0-or-more letters... though there were also other letters.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which regex flavor (which programming language) you're using, but you might want to consider either

```
^\p{L}*$
```

if your regex flavor supports Unicode properties or

```
^[^\W\d_]*$
```

if it doesn't.

Reason: Your regex will allow only unaccented letters and Ñ - is there a real language that uses the latter without also having accented letters?

`\p{L}` means "any letter in any 'language'",

`[^\W\d_]` means "any character that is neither a non-alphanumeric, a digit or an underscore", which is just a fancy but necessary way to say "any letter" (`\w` is a shorthand for "letter, digit or underscore", `\W` is the inverse of that).